# Count number of occurrences of a pattern in a file (even on same line)

Tags: search, count, grep, match

When searching for number of occurrences of a string in a file, I generally use:

```
grep pattern file | wc -l
```

However, this only finds one occurrence per line, because of the way grep works. How can I search for the number of times a string appears in a file, regardless of whether they are on the same or different lines?

Also, what if I'm searching for a regex pattern, not a simple string? How can I count those, or, even better, print each match on a new line?

Answer (score 167, accepted):

To count all occurrences, use `-o`. Try this:

```
echo afoobarfoobar | grep -o foo | wc -l
```

And `man grep` of course (:

#### Update

Some suggest to use just `grep -co foo` instead of `grep -o foo | wc -l`.

Don't.

This shortcut won't work in all cases. Man page says:

```
-c print a count of matching lines
```

Difference in these approaches is illustrated below:

1.

```
$ echo afoobarfoobar | grep -oc foo
1
```

As soon as the match is found **in the line** (`a{foo}barfoobar`) the searching stops. Only one line was checked and it matched, so the output is `1`. Actually `-o` is ignored here and you could just use `grep -c` instead.

2.

```
$ echo afoobarfoobar | grep -o foo
foo
foo

$ echo afoobarfoobar | grep -o foo | wc -l
2
```

Two matches are found in the line (`a{foo}bar{foo}bar`) because we explicitly asked to find every **occurrence** (`-o`). Every occurence is printed on a separate line, and `wc -l` just counts the number of lines in the output.

Comment: Wow... is it really that simple?

Comment: grep -oc does not work in this case. Try echo afoobarfoobar | grep -oc foo

Comment: Is there no way to do this for multiple files? Let's say I want to see the number of occurrences per file on a set of files. I can do it *per line* with grep -c *, but not per instance.

Comment: `grep -o foo a.txt b.txt | sort | uniq -c` works just fine (with GNU grep): https://gist.github.com/hudolejev/81a05791f38cbacfd4de3ee3b44eb4f8

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
grep "string to search for" FileNameToSearch | cut -d ":" -f 4 | sort -n | uniq -c
```

Sample:

```
grep "SMTP connect from unknown" maillog | cut -d ":" -f 4 | sort -n | uniq -c
  6  SMTP connect from unknown [188.190.118.90]
 54  SMTP connect from unknown [62.193.131.114]
  3  SMTP connect from unknown [91.222.51.253]
```

Answer (score 2):

[Ripgrep](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep/releases/tag/0.9.0), which is a fast alternative to grep, has just introduced the `--count-matches` flag allowing counting **each** match in version 0.9 (I'm using the above example to stay consistent):

```
> echo afoobarfoobar | rg --count foo
1
> echo afoobarfoobar | rg --count-matches foo
2
```

As asked by OP, ripgrep allows for regex pattern as well (`--regexp <PATTERN>`).
Also it can print each (line) match on a separate line:

```
> echo -e "line1foo\nline2afoobarfoobar" | rg foo
line1foo
line2afoobarfoobar
```

Answer (score 1):

A belated post:
Use the search regex pattern  as a Record Separator (RS) in `awk`
This allows your regex to span `\n`-delimited lines (if you need it).

```
printf 'X \n moo X\n XX\n' | 
   awk -vRS='X[^X]*X' 'END{print (NR<2?0:NR-1)}'
```

Answer (score -1):

Hack grep's color function, and count how many color tags it prints out:

```
echo -e "a\nb  b b\nc\ndef\nb e brb\nr" \
| GREP_COLOR="033" grep --color=always  b \
| perl -e 'undef $/; $_=<>; s/\n//g; s/\x1b\x5b\x30\x33\x33/\n/g; print $_' \
| wc -l
```