# Count specified words in file

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I want to make script, that finds how many words, that I chose, are in my chosen file.

Here is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Iveskite reiksme kurios kurios kurios ieskosime faile"
read reiksme
echo "Nurodykite faila kuriame ieskosime reiksmes"
read failas
kiek=$(awk '/$reiksme/' $failas | wc -l)
echo $kiek > kiek.txt
```

if $failas contains lines like:

```
$reiksme
$reiksme
$reiksme
```

then it's ok, but if `$failas` contains lines like:

```
$reiksme $reiksme
random word $reiksme $reiksme
random random $reiksme
```

Then my script fails to count how many words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

awk is only splitting on lines.  You could do it in a few steps, though there may well be easier ways than this:

```
kiek=$(sed -e 's/\s/\n/g' $failas | grep "\b${reiksme}\b" | wc -l)
```

to replace all whitespace with newline, then use grep (or your awk if you like) to find what you're looking for then count them

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer on my own. I just changed

```
kiek=$(awk '/$reiksme/' $failas | wc -l)
```

to

```
kiek=$(tr -cs 'A-Za-z' '\n' < $failas | grep -c "$reiksme")
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this with `grep` is to use the `-o` option as described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2908757/count-number-of-occurrences-of-a-pattern-in-a-file-even-on-same-line). Putting it together for you:

```
kiek=$(grep -o "${reiksme}" | wc -l)
```