# finding number of occurences in large text file in linux

Tags: linux, grep

I have a 17 GB txt file and i cannot seem to load it via `vim`. Researched on solutions provided here. However i do not seem to understand them very well and i am not good with linux or perl.

I understand i would have to use grep or something.

```
grep -oP "/^2" file
```

I have tried up to this code but i cannot seem to find the solution to output the number of occurences without printing all the lines to screen

I would like to find the number of lines that starts with a digit 2 in the file and output the number to shell.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2908757/count-number-of-occurrences-of-a-pattern-in-a-file-even-on-same-line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to continue using PCRE:

```
grep -cP ^2 file
```

Using grep's "basic regular expressions":

```
grep -c ^2 file
```

Comment: Output the number of lines that start with the digit 2? Yeah.

Comment: I read the documentation it says -c is for count. So it also takes a regex as a parameter?

Comment: You caught me. I lied the first two times.