# Bash - count a pattern and print the line containing the pattern

Tags: regex, bash, pattern-matching

everyone! While I was reading this discussion, "[Count number of occurrences of a pattern in a file (even on same line)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2908757/count-number-of-occurrences-of-a-pattern-in-a-file-even-on-same-line/2912711#2912711)", I wondered if I could add the line containing the pattern next to the count values.

Somehow I wasn't able to add any comment on the discussion, so I'm posting a new question. Can somebody en-light me?

---

There must be some misunderstanding here, so I put an example.
Let's say, I have a DNA sequence like below and want to find out how many 'CG' are present in each line.

```
ACAAAGAACTCAAGAAGTTGGACCCCAGAGAACCAAATAACCCTATTAAA
AATTCGGAACAGAGATAAACAAAGAATTCTCAACTGAGGAAACTTGAATG
GGATTTTTTTTTAAGATTCACTTATTTTTATTTTCTGCATGAGTGTTTGC
CTCGATGTATGTACATATACGACATGTGTACGTGGTGCGCAAGTAAGCAG
```

Additionally, I want to print each line (not the pattern) along with the pattern counts.

```
0 ACAAAGAACTCAAGAAGTTGGACCCCAGAGAACCAAATAACCCTATTAAA
1 AATTCGGAACAGAGATAAACAAAGAATTCTCAACTGAGGAAACTTGAATG
0 GGATTTTTTTTTAAGATTCACTTATTTTTATTTTCTGCATGAGTGTTTGC
4 CTCGATGTATGTACATATACGACATGTGTACGTGGTGCGCAAGTAAGCAG
```

I wish the example above will help to understand the question better.

Thank you!

Comment: post an example along with expected output.

Comment: Manage a hash table in this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found a really simple and elegant solution using EXCEL.
The formula goes like below...

```
=(LEN(B2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B2,"CG","")))/2
```

What this formula basically does is it counts total length of strings in a cell and length after removal of the pattern ("CG" in this case), then subtract them. Since each "CG" is replaced by blanks, 2 strings are missing after substitution, and you can get the number of the pattern by dividing it with length of your pattern which is 2 in this case.

For example, following sequence contains 50 strings and 13 CG's.

```
CAGTGCACACAACACATGTACGCGCGCGCGCGCGCGCGCGCGCGCGTGTG  50
```

After substituting "CG" to blanks, you get 24 strings.

```
CAGTGCACACAACACATGTATGTG  24
```

To count the "CG" occurances,

```
(50-24)/2 = 13
```

If you are looking for "CAG", enter "CAG" instead of "CG" and divide by 3.
How simple is that!

You can see the original post in the following link.

http://fiveminutelessons.com/learn-microsoft-excel/count-occurrences-single-character-cell-excel#sthash.H4VfOkGB.dpbs

English is not my primary language, so please understand errors in my writing.

People are geniuses!

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
printf 'pattern' | tee >(sed 's/$/ : /') | grep -cf - input.txt
```

Taking help of `tee` and process substitution.

**Example:**

```
% cat file.txt 
foobar
spamegg
foo

% printf 'foo' | tee >(sed 's/$/ : /') | grep -cf - file.txt 
foo : 2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
cat fileName | grep pattern | uniq -c
```