# grep a character/word from a string and count number of occurrences in Linux

Tags: linux

I like to a grep a character from a string then count it, I don't see from google search. Please advise. I might miss search for it.

```
node_count=`echo "test1|test2|test3" | grep "|" |wc -l`|echo $node_count
```

output is always 1 to me.

```
1
```

Remember that I don't grep from a file but a line of string. Grep from a file is easy.

Comment: Expected behavior. Run the test without the *`wc`*. One line is output *`test1|test2|test3`* but it contains two pipe symbols.

Comment: Thanks. so how can I achieve to get number of "|" in this example? the pipe between testx are just example but it can be ; or other special char, the outcome is same

Comment: *`echo "test1|test2|test3" | grep -o "|" | wc -l`*. Also see [Count total number of occurrences using grep](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/6979/56041), [Count number of occurrences of a pattern in a file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2908757/608639) and friends.

Comment: You are good! Appreciate! I did not see that link. Sorry. I missed -L

Comment: Thanks, jww. I will search more carefully next time. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to use option `-o` of `grep`:

```
$ node_count=`echo "test1|test2|test3" | grep  "|" -o |wc -l` && echo $node_count
# 2
```

Comment: I did this way | grep -o "|" |wc -l`|echo $node_count
 but I should echo $node_count on second line. Darn. Thanks again